# I have 2 startActivityForResult and 2 onActivityResult, second one starts correctly but trys to return the firsts ones data?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have 2 buttons that both call startActivityForResult and onActivityResult separately. The first is a contact picker, the second a picture picker. The first one operates correctly and returns the appropriate contact number to my eddittext as it should. The second starts as it should and allows me to choose a picture from my gallery, but does not return the picture to my imagview as it should. I think its trying to return the data from the first one and cant figure out how to distinguish the first from the second. I'm new to android, still learning, making mistakes, and any help as to where and how I went wrong would be appreciated. My code in question is below.

```
Button.OnClickListener buttonClickListener3 = new Button.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View contact) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        }};

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

          if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Uri contactData = data.getData();
                Cursor cur = managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
                ContentResolver contect_resolver = getContentResolver();

                if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
                    String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(BaseColumns._ID));
                    String name = "";
                    String no = "";

                    Cursor phoneCur = contect_resolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[] { id }, null);

                    if (phoneCur.moveToFirst()) {
                        name = phoneCur.getString(phoneCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                        no = phoneCur.getString(phoneCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    }

                    Log.e("Phone no & name :***: ", name + " : " + no);
                    txt.append(name + " : " + no + "/n");

                    id = null;
                    name = null;
                    no = null;
                    phoneCur = null;
                }
                contect_resolver = null;
                cur = null;

            }
    }


    Button.OnClickListener buttonClickListener4 = new Button.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View ChoosePictureButton) {
          Intent choosePictureIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI); 
          startActivityForResult(choosePictureIntent, 2);


        }};


        public void onActivityResult2(int requestCode2, int resultCode2, Intent intent) {
          super.onActivityResult(requestCode2, resultCode2, intent);


          if (resultCode2 == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri imageFileUri = intent.getData();

            try {
              BitmapFactory.Options bmpFactoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
              bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
              Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageFileUri), null, bmpFactoryOptions);
              bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = 2;
              bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
              bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(
                      imageFileUri), null, bmpFactoryOptions);

              ChosenImageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
              Log.v("ERROR", e.toString());
            }
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using a single onActivityResult() like below

```
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

      if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
switch(reqCode)
{
 case 1:
            Uri contactData = data.getData();
            Cursor cur = managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
            ContentResolver contect_resolver = getContentResolver();

            if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
                String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(BaseColumns._ID));
                String name = "";
                String no = "";

                Cursor phoneCur = contect_resolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[] { id }, null);

                if (phoneCur.moveToFirst()) {
                    name = phoneCur.getString(phoneCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    no = phoneCur.getString(phoneCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                }

                Log.e("Phone no & name :***: ", name + " : " + no);
                txt.append(name + " : " + no + "/n");

                id = null;
                name = null;
                no = null;
                phoneCur = null;
            }
            contect_resolver = null;
            cur = null;

        }
}
break ;

case 2:
        Uri imageFileUri = intent.getData();

        try {
          BitmapFactory.Options bmpFactoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
          bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
              Bitmap bmp =  
   BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageFileUri), null,  
 bmpFactoryOptions);
          bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = 2;
          bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
          bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(
                  imageFileUri), null, bmpFactoryOptions);

          ChosenImageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
          Log.v("ERROR", e.toString());
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Try using something like the above

Comment: Hmm couldnt get that switch statement to work properly however you did give me an idea to try if(reqCode == 1) {do stuff} and else if(reqCode == 2) {do stuff} but still cant get it to return the selected picture.

Comment: Any idea why it still wouldnt return the picture from the gallery tho?

Comment: are you with the solution now?

Comment: Got it working, took some more tinkering, much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

In your onClickListener, call getId on the view being passed in, and call startActivityForResult with different request codes, depending on the id of the button. Then in your onActivityResult, switch depending on the request code it receives.

Comment: Any chance you could give an example? I tend to pick things up easier that way.